# Google chrome and chrome webdriver are installed in Ubuntu but still driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver') fails

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Ubuntu.
I installed google chrome and linux chrome driver successfully.

I imported the following :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

All these imports happen successfully.
Post that I tried to run the following code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

It gave the following error :
**selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)**

I went to powershell and checked where google chrome and chromedriver are installed :
[image]

I see that they are installed in the correct path. But why isn't the code working then? why is it giving an error?

Please any help would be immensely appreciated!!

Comment: Try running your program as root and use the current version of webdriver with current browser.

Comment: I wonder about two things: 
1. Why we have the `chromedriver` both in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin/` when only one is sufficient.
2. If the `chromedriver` is already at a place which is part of `PATH` variable, then what is the need of specifying path in `webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: @SwaroopHumane what do you mean by running the program as root?

Comment: @Genius I have no answer to this. I googled... I copy pasted the commands. that is all.

Comment: @Genius I ran it without specifying the path also. It gave the same error.

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/ @SoumyaPandey this is the place where you get the right webdiver.
Delete the old one from both places `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` and put the new one at `/usr/bin`. Now start python in a new terminal and just do: 
from selenium import webdriver ; 
driver = webdriver.Chrome() ; also make sure you have the latest version of Chrome, and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @Genius while installing it I used this link only. wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip

Answer (score 0):

This issue started on Google Chrome version 90. Version 89 worked just fine. I was hoping Google would fix it on version 91 but still has the same problem.